# How to access the working directory in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory

Using [Google Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb), when I use the `imwrite()` function of [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) to save an image, it saves it, but I cannot access it.

I don't know how to access the folder to be able to view my saved image.

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

The output is:

> /content

Answer (score 0):

did you install the drive in google Colab? if not then install it and log into your google drive to get key and the image will be saved there

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Comment: Ok got it.But after getting the key, where should I enter it?

Comment: I have entered it. now where can I find the content folder?

Comment: now when you save the folder you find it under your google drive